# iOS App doesn't show up in Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am trying to get my app reporting crashes on Crashlytics.

For some reason my iOS app still doesn't show up on the dashboard of Fabric.

I've followed the documentation and everything builds successfully. https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

I've enabled the debug mode and crashes seem to get sent:

```
MyApp[1961:1822425] [Crashlytics] Version 3.8.4 (121)
MyApp[1961:1822425] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id '1c33af19c4e2424289b5f83bd639007d' for submission
MyApp[1961:1822433] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
MyApp[1961:1822433] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting async /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3D82EEEA-EDC6-4B19-A065-2FBDA067C49D/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.myorg.myapp/v3/prepared/2419B75F-DAB2-47C6-8225-C400440F731B.multipartmime
MyApp[1961:1822435] [Crashlytics:Crash:Client] A task currently exists for this upload, skipping
MyApp[1961:1822436] [Fabric] settings downloaded successfully
MyApp[1961:1822436] [Fabric] Settings are available for consumption
MyApp[1961:1822435] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3D82EEEA-EDC6-4B19-A065-2FBDA067C49D/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/com.myorg.myapp/v3/prepared/2419B75F-DAB2-47C6-8225-C400440F731B.multipartmime
MyApp[1961:1822435] [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
```

But still, I've waited for a few hours, still not showing up.

I have tried a debug scheme as well as release scheme, on VPN and without VPN.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Looking at the manual installation documentation, I get my app showing up:

[image]

But it doesn't show up during the last phase, the build. The system seems to make the request to an API to get my app data though.

[image]

[image]

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: please check your dashboard and see are you getting  error from crashlytics saying "unable to symbolicate please upload dsym file"?

Comment: I don't even have the iOS app showing up. Only the Android one. So I can't access any dashboard for the iOS app. From what I see there is no error anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't look like you have your bundle ID setup correctly. Right now we are seeing it as com.myorg.myapp, which is the default blank.

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: It's 2019 and I'm still having the same issue. How did you solve this?

Comment: I stopped using Fabric

Comment: haha what's the better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've contacted Fabric support (support@fabric.io). They activated my app manually. Here is their answer:

> I have activated your app  that was in "Settings Configured" status -
>   App received a run event, but not a build event.

Funny story...